# AngularJs How passing arguments to $scope.$apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, arguments

I want pass arguments from directive to controller.
Into html i have:

```
<div id="myTest" class="scrollable-content" scrolly="inScroll(value)">
```

My directive is:

```
app.directive('scrolly', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('loading directive');

        element.bind('scroll', function () {
            var value = 1;
            alert(attrs.scrolly);
            scope.$apply(attrs.scrolly);
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

into controller i have:

```
$scope.inScroll = function(value) {
  alert(value);
};
```

When i scroll the page, the directive set the value = 1; and then call the function inScroll(value), but the function receive value undefined

Can you help me?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

just replace

> var value = 1;

with

> scope.value = 1;